# Combining files into multiIndex dataframe in python and finally export to txt

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a couple of files that all have the same first column (`X`), and the same column names (`X`, `B`, `C`), but the second and third column are different values.

```
X  | B | C
-----------
a    0   2
b    4   9
...
z    3   0
```

I want to combine all these tables into one big dataframe, but with the addition that each part is accessible through its own index, for instance based on the filename. E.g. `df['f1']['B']` would be `[0, 4..., 3]`. The end result would look like this.

```
   | f1 | f1 | f2 | f2 
X  | B  | C  | B  | C
-----------------------
a    0    2    3    2
b    4    9    1    2
...        
z    3    0    9    8
```

This is the code I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import regex as re

dir = 'directory'
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), dir))
# List all files in folder
filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if re.match(".*\.txt$", name)]

r_coln = re.compile(r"\.txt$")

frames = []

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    filename = filenames[i]
    coln = r_coln.sub("", filename)
    if (i == 0):
        # Subtract the first column which is identical for all frames
        first_frame =  pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, filename), usecols=[0], sep="\t", names=[''], header=None)
        frames.append(first_frame)

    # Get frame with a new header
    frames.append(pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, filename), usecols=[1, 2], sep="\t", names=[coln, ''], header=None))

# Combine all frames
df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

This works in that the resulting dataframe does indeed look like the example I posted above with the exception that I only have one 'top' heading per file. Using `names=[coln, coln]` instead of `names=[coln, '']` caused one of the two columns to get dropped (and I do not know why). However, it isn't multi-indexed. In other words, I cannot access `df['f1']['B']` because it returns the error `KeyError: 'B'`. I am looking for a way to make this possible. Either by transforming the resulting `df` after the read-in loop, or by changing something inside the loop.

Finally, I'd also like to export this dataframe to a tab-separated text file.

Comment: You can use the `keys` argument in `pd.concat`. It automatically creates a multi-index and adds an upper level to it consisting of passed keys.  (`names` adds names for the levels.) Also, you probably want to set `X` as an index first - either with the `.set_index` method or with the `index_col` argument to `pd.read_csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - Adding a one-liner, credits to @ptrj.

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('X'),df2.set_index('X')],axis=1,keys = ['F1','F2'])

In []: df
Out[]:
      F1    F2
    B  C  B   C
X
a  0  2  0   4
b  4  9  8  18
z  3  0  6   0
```

---

Alternative Solution :

You can define a MultiIndex from arrays.

Let's start with two sample DataFrame.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'B': {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 3},
                   'C': {0: 2, 1: 9, 2: 0},
                   'X': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'z'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': {0: 0, 1: 8, 2: 6},
                   'C': {0: 4, 1: 18, 2: 0},
                   'X': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'z'}})

# Merge the DataFrames
merged = df1.merge(df2,on='X').set_index('X')

# Create a MultiIndex
arrays = [['F1','F1','F2','F2'], ['B','C','B','C']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['level1', 'level2'])

# Create your DataFrame    

df = pd.DataFrame(data=merged.as_matrix(),
                  columns=columns,
                  index = df1['X'])
```

`df` now looks like :

```
level1    F1      F2
level2  B   C   B   C
    X               
    a   0   2   0   4
    b   4   9   8   18
    z   3   0   6   0
```

Now, you can index it using `df['F1']`

```
level2  B   C
   X        
   a    0   2
   b    4   9
   z    3   0
```

Or, `df['F1']['B']`, which gives you :

```
0    0
1    4
2    3
```

---

Edit : @Bram Vanroy [extended this solution](http://pastebin.com/7L7VCzxm) to work with multiple DataFrames.

Comment: After fixing some typos you made, it works. However, the X columns are still visible.

Comment: @BramVanroy - Apologies! I made some changes, can you try again?

Comment: [However, the X columns are still visible ] try .......    list(df['F1']['B'].values)

Comment: Nice! I edited it also allow for more than 2 dataframes to merge. Maybe there is a better way, but this is what I came up with. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7L7VCzxm). Maybe you can take this into account in your answer?

Comment: With the alternative single line solution using `pd.concat`, it gets a lot easier to extend to multiple DataFrames. I'll edit my answer to add a link to your code. Cheers!

Comment: @BramVanroy This one liner does the same: `pd.concat([df.set_index('X') for df in dfs], axis=1, keys=['F{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(dfs))])`

Comment: @ptrj Thank you for that. However, unless that solution has an efficiency improvement, I'd rather stick wuth user666's solutin due to its readability!

Comment: @BramVanroy It's ok, readability is important. I put a oneliner only to show my idea. (Here, one `concat` seemed to me more natural than multiple `merge`'s. I'd also expect it to be faster - but I didn't measure.)